# Android - safest way to connect to MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, security, database-connection, http-post

I'm developping an Android app which uses the same MySQL server as a website is using.

I want to connect to the database in my app, and I've done that before by placing some PHP files on the server and use a HTTP post and retrieve the response in json format. I don't know why - I'm not a specialist - but this just doesn't look like a very safe way to me.

Using a SOAP or REST webservice looks safer to me, but I don't know how to deploy those on a server (the server is not mine, I don't want to fool around too much with it).

So what is the safest way for me then?

And if I'm using PHP scripts, should I store the database credentials in the PHP scripts or in my application and pass them to the PHP script? What's the safest of these?

Thanks

Comment: Your previously selected solution (php/post/json) is just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your choice of "envelope-technology" has no effect on security. In security architecture terms, plain php pages, REST-like architectures and SOAP services are all identical - you are still sending and receiving the exact identical information over the same channel. It is just *wrapped up* in a different way. No additional protection is given.

As for your credentials, it is best to store them in a file that lives outside of the web server's documentroot - this limits your exposure if a seperate vulnerability allows your website files to be enumerated or read. Your PHP program can `require_once` the credentials file.

If users can have information stored that is specific to them, you will need to use authentication and authorisation to ensure that one use cannot act on another user's behalf.

Oh, and don't allow GET requests to change your data. Require that all state-changing or destructive actions can only be performed with POST requests. This will limit the risk of damage to you data from user-agents/proxies that pre-cache requests, or replay requests and from users/search-robots browsing around your site.

Comment: Thank you, I used this way for school once and they said it wasn't secure. But perhaps that was because I wasn't using stored procedures? The teacher just changed the query to 'TRUNCATE TABLE ...'. I have no idea how that was possible. But I don't have HTTPS connection so I didn't know if the security was alright.

Comment: Your insecurity came from the details of your code's contents and the way it built an SQL query; not from your choice of higher-level architecture. Regarding your teacher's comments, you need to read up on SQL Injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection. Stored procedures are one mechanism to avoid sqli, but parameterised prepared statements work just as well.

Comment: [obligatory xkcd reference] This happened at school? Are you little bobby tables? http://xkcd.com/327/  :-)

Comment: lol! I mailed my teacher, he said he read the HTTP header response and saw the URL of the webservice to delete products, so he created this script:
`<form action="http://169.254.254.254/deleteProduct.php" method="get">
<input name="Bestelling_Bes_id" value="#x"><br>
<input name="Product_Pro_id" value="#y"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>`
And then he just used a loop for all the #x and #y values. He said the biggest problem with our security was the fact that he could submit that form without being logged in, how can I prevent that?

Comment: right yes. no need even for sql injection then :-)  You need to research user authentication (and authorisation perhaps) and session handling in php. There's a ton of tutorials on the googles https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=user+login+php+tutorial .  It is also a good idea to require POST requests for any actions that make data changes, this makes it harder to cause damage when a user or search robot browses around your site.

Comment: I know PHP pretty well, I'm also developing in Zend now. But how should I do this in my case, with the Android app. Pass the login and password for my user to the PHP script? But how does that make my app any safer, because you can still read the login and password in the HTTP headers? Thank you for your quick responses by the way, I appreciate your help

Comment: If you don't want the user/pass to be network-sniffable, you need to use HTTPS.